# Grease pencil - No object selection

Tags: cycles-render-engine, grease-pencil

I am trying to follow a tutorial that uses the grease pencil to change the way the cell fracture fractures.

[image]

This is the screenshot from the video featuring the scene or object menu.

[image]

And this is all that shows on my screen. Is this because of the difference in versions? The video and me are using Cycles

Comment: It seems that selecting the object, drawing, then deselecting it makes the lines not show. Maybe this is the alternative to the "Object" and "Scene"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting is now located in the *Tool Shelf* <kbd>T</kbd> under *Grease Pencil*.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've checked, it truly is all about selecting the object and drawing to make the pencil layer on the object, not on the scene.

> It seems that selecting the object, drawing, then deselecting it makes the lines not show. Maybe this is the alternative to the "Object" and "Scene"?

Note: Any answers with additional information are welcome and I will accept the best one.

Comment: This is the answer. It's similar the the render border feature, you can have different gp strokes for individual objects which appear when they are selected if you chose object or one that sits in the scene.